# TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined at Object.eval angular 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular6, angular7

I am trying to delete a product. but this error shows on my console.
This is my HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of products; let i = index;">
    <td><input [(ngModel)]="checked[i].selected" type="checkbox" name="selectproduct" value="{{p.productId}}"></td>
    <td>{{p.productCode}}</td>
    <td>{{p.productName}}</td>
    <td>{{p.productDes}}</td>
    <td>{{p.flag}}</td>
    <td>{{p.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is my component.ts file

```
getSelected() {
    let result = this.checked.filter((ch) => { return ch.selected })
      .map((ch) => { return ch.value });
    return (result);
  }

  deleteProducts(productids = this.getSelected()) {
    this.rest.deleteProducts(productids).subscribe((data: {}) => {
    });
    debugger;
    this.getProducts();
  }
```

This is my Service.ts

```
deleteProducts(productIds): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(endpoint + 'Delete', productIds, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
  }
```

Comment: have u verified that the 'checked' array in your component has values when it is in 'getSelected()' method?

Comment: Have you got the solution?